# Some strings are empty in AJAX POST response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, response

I am making an AJAX POST request with a JSON response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ApiServiceVdc,
  type: 'POST',
  data: lepost,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var detail = '';
    detail += '<b>' + data.media.titre + '</b>';
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('Erreur système !');
  }
});
```

Here's the response of my ApiServiceVdc :

```
media: {
  id: 1,
  type: 1,
  titre: "Jet d'eau vers Cologny",
  alias: "jet-d-eau-vers-cologny",
}
```

The ApiServiceVdc is made with PHP7 code using the correct header

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

The values `titre` and `alias` are empty! I'm unable to use them. What did I do wrong? It's working in other scripts on other servers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If that's the response from the request then the values are populated. How are you determining that they are empty? It appears that you do nothing with the `detail` variable, so if you're expecting a change in the DOM, that may be the reason.

Comment: Someday I got a problem similar to this, I had CORS problem and I got a way to get the answer using jsonp. Eventhough I got the information in the body of response, when I tried to use the data I got null.

Comment: In the PHP code of ApiServiceVdc, i force the value to String with strval() ... if i dont do that, the response is «undefined» ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know, thats why I said that I got the way to get the values using jsonp. Eventhough I was able to see it from the web browser console I was not able to get it from the script.

Comment: @SwissGeckO why not just use `json_encode`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The Api has json_encode to print result : « echo json_encode($dataout); »

Comment: I'd suggest you debug this step by step. Firstly use the console to see what is returned to the request, and in what format. Then try and `console.log(data)` in the success handler. Then finally log one of the specific properties to ensure it has a value there too. You've still not explained why you believe the values are empty in the request. One last thing - is this request to the local domain?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your help ! the request is on local domain .... in the console, i see the «data» response .... and titre and alias is ""

Comment: Here's the console.log(data) :
    media:
alias: ""
categories: (2) [{…}, {…}]
id: 2
params: (2) ["12", "3000x4000"]
titre: ""
type: 1
__proto__: Object

Comment: If i try to extract «titre» value in the console ... i have response :
Titre : 
With nothing printed

Comment: Given that output the problem is with the PHP code that is returning the response, not the JS which is retrieving it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like titre and alias are not empty from your response. 
If you want a change in your page, you need to append that "detail" to your DOM. 
Is that what you are asking? 
If not, try putting `dataType: "json"` in your ajax request.

Comment: Is this your response? 
media: {
  id: 1,
  type: 1,
  titre: "Jet d'eau vers Cologny",
  alias: "jet-d-eau-vers-cologny",
}

So you are sure that the values do not return empty from your API, right?